# prefill second dropdown box based on first dropdown box value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prefill second dropdown list based on first dropdown list values.... its working fine if i use **school_bag** instead of **school bag** [space b/w 2 words] or **school(bag)** [if we use charactar **(** ] , but  i want to make it work if i use **school bag or school(bag)** also....

[image]

```
<select name="meal" id="meal" onChange="changecat(this.value);">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    <option value="school bag">school bag</option>
    <option value="school(bag)">school(bag)</option>   
</select>
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
</select>

<script>
var mealsByCategory = {
    school bag: ["Soup", "Juice", "Tea", "Others"],
    school(bag): ["Soup", "Juice", "Water", "Others"],

}

    function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (categoryId in mealsByCategory[value]) {
                catOptions += "<option>" + mealsByCategory[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Try using "school (bag)": [ ... ], and you could try using a different approach, like
`bag1 = { 
    name: "school (bag),
    elements: [ ... ] 
}`

Comment: @CommunityIsridiculous sorry, i am new to js, thanks, please post your comment as answer

Comment: Its all right, we all start somewhere. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using 
`"school (bag)": [ ... ]` and you could try using a different approach, like var

```
bag1 = { 
   name: "school (bag), 
   elements: [ ... ] 
}
```

Comment: also how i can write these 2 lines in one line : line 1 : `"school (bag)": ["Soup", "Juice", "Tea", "Others"], line 2 :"school bag":   ["Soup", "Juice", "Tea", "Others"],`

Comment: You could use this. `var mealsByCategory = { "school bag": ["Soup", "Juice", "Tea", "Others"], "school(bag)": ["Soup", "Juice", "Water", "Others"] }`

Comment: sorry, not like that, can i do something like this : `"school (bag)" ,  "school bag": ["Soup", "Juice", "Tea", "Others"],` ?

Comment: You mean using same elements for both arrays?

Comment: Try this. `var mealsByCategory = { "school bag": arrTMP = ["Soup", "Juice", "Tea", "Others"], "school (bag)": arrTMP }`

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked, by the way, I would recommend reading something about arrays in javascript, for example [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-array-methods-in-javascript-iteration-methods) after this you would most likely understand arrays in javascript :) or this is fine aswell [link](http://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array/)